# Hybrid Model/Controller Validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am looking to have a user enter in a URL to an image on a form. I already have this built. I would like for two different things to happen, but I was wondering if I could somehow combine them.

When the user submits the form, I would like the URL to be validated, not only that it takes on a valid url format, but that it actually exists.

I would also like to set an integer in the database depending on the type of document the URL points to. If it is an image, I would like an integer field on the record (let's call it 'file_type') to be set to 1. If it is not an image, I would like the validation to fail.

Is there any way to validate the URL while also collecting data for the record? I ask this because I believe it makes much more sense for the server to make the request once rather than twice, once for validation, and once for storing file type.

Is this possible? What would you suggest?
Thanks!

Comment: i think you could achieve this with making request to selected url, and depending on responce code(200, 400, 404, etc) you can make your decision if this url valid, and exists.